# How to add html line break after each item in Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, html, string, web-component, polymer-3.x

I would like to display a list in my web component, with a line break, the problem is that my function that loops on the list is in Javascript, and I call it in my html. How can I do it?

I tried :

- `result.join("\n");` //this work on console
- ``` result.join( html ``<br/>``); ``` //(Windsor[object HTMLTemplateElement]groot )
- `result.push(value,"\n");` //(Windsor, ,groot)

Javascript

```
_getValues(field) 
{

    switch (field.type) {
...

default:

          if (this.values.length) {
            for (const [index, value] of this.values.entries()) {
              result.push(value);
            }
            return result;
          } else 
          return (this.values);
}
```

HTMLTemplate Polymer 3.0

```
static get template() {
    return html `
...
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fields}}">
                    <span><b> item :</b> <br> [[_getValues(item)]] </span>  
                </template> `
```

I expect the output in the IHM like this :

```
Windsor
groot
```

But i have this :

```
Windsor,groot
```

or 
 Windsor,,groot 
 or 
 Windsor[object HTMLTemplateElement]groot

Comment: Use CSS and set each element as `display:block`

Comment: I cannot access to each element and add CSS from Javascript, if you have an idea how to do it i will take it.

Comment: `<div><span> <b> item </b></span> <br> <div style = "display:block"> [[_getValues(item)]] </div></div>` Doesn't work @Liam

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would work if your fields object looked more like this

```
fields : [
 {name: 'Windsor', value: 'groot'}
]

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fields}}">
                        <div><b> name :</div> <div> value </div>  
                    </template>
```

If calling your function in the template is working then this should work as well

```
<div><b> item :</b></div> <div> [[_getValues(item)]] </div>
```

Comment: I tried this but not work `<div><span> <b> item </b></span> <br> <div style = "display:block"> [[_getValues(item)]] </div></div> ` @Leonardo

Comment: What did it display? Is it displaying the correct values?
https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/1tr3L4wq/
your html should work unless there is overarching css preventing it from doing so

Comment: The problem is not with the fields, but with the values. Example : field is family name, values are Windsor,groot. it gives this : family name : Windsor,groot.
I pass a field to my function that does a processing and return the corresponding values as an array. I hope I have explained it well there. https://jsfiddle.net/rfa3sxc5/1/ @Leonardo

Comment: @HamzaBdr it looks like youre having an issue with your function. My suggestion would be to create the object that you want to iterate through before sending it to the DOM.

Comment: Yes i created it, the object is result. The problem is that i can't return value by value, i need to return an array to display all values.. @Leonardo

Comment: so your object is {familyName : 'Windsor, Groot'} and you want the values comma separated  in its own line?